Benefits of Kalman Filter vs numerically approximating some values for inverted pendulum on cart?
I've been working on an inverted pendulum on a cart with a Linear Quadratic Regulator as my first-ever control system project, since it's a classic. I used a stepper motor, which I admit was a bit strange of a choice, but I was on a deadline and had to do something. What I do is calculate my actuation force $u(t)$, and calculate $\ddot x$ which I have reign over since I can just simulate an acceleration on my stepper.
I am not using a Kalman Filter at the moment. My four states are $x$, $v$, $\theta$, and $\omega$. I have a stepper motor so obviously I know $x$ and a rotary encoder tells me $\theta$. I'm currently numerically approximating $v$ and $\omega$ by keeping track of delta-times between updates to $x$ and $\theta$, and the system is decently stable, never falling when left alone, but it's lacking a lot of robustness. When it gets near the top fixed point, it can hold it and respond to disturbance, but it oscillates around it and never finds a very stable location.
Should I be using a Kalman Filter? Would it really be much better than what I'm doing at the moment? I'm just starting out with these concepts and would like some opinions. Thank you

Have you tried tuning your LQR controller terms to make it oscillate less / be more robust?

Yes I've tried increasing the actuation cost and made the bias the same for all states but the effect doesn't seem to really go away

"...but it oscillates around it..." 1 could be friction / stiction in the system at the $\theta$ joint or the wheel joint. 2 could be the jerkiness associated with stepper discrete steps. 3 encoders don't give output if stationery. So estimate of the derivative becomes  poor. If any one of this is the reason, would a Kalman filter help? What is the amplitude of the oscillation versus the resolution of the encoder?

Have you done any simulation with ideal plant and non ideal plant models? Do those computer simulations also show oscillation?

Supposing your filters and control laws are digital, did you take into account how quickly you are sampling or commanding? Also supposing you have an encoder, did you account for what happens to the input you expect to get when it stops moving?

@AJN That’s actually an interesting comment about the encoder not showing it’s stationary. I’m only updating theta and omega using interrupts, so omega only updates when the encoder position changes, and this is limited by its resolution. I wonder if this would be the issue

Do a system analysis or a numerical simulation that takes your encoder quantization into account.  See if the predicted amount of movement is close to the amount of movement you see in the real deal.  If you don't know what I'm talking about, or how to do it, ask another question.
